# define definition of a variable in phpstorm in (php) yii application

Tags: php, yii, autocomplete, phpstorm

in a Yii Application in PHPStorm i have the following Code:

```
$datasource = Yii::app()->someComponent;
```

PHPStorm is now not able to find the definition of method parameters in autocomplete, if i write

```
$datasource->aMethod(
```

Is there a way to tell phpstorm the source in order to have a working autocomplete?, e.g.

```
// @definition components/SomeComponent.php
$datasource = Yii::app()->someComponent;
```

Thanks,

markus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a PHP Doc comment to tell PHPStorm which type the var has.

```
/** @var SomeClassName $datasource */
$datasource = Yii::app()->someComponent;
```

Answer (score 1):

There's better solution. One which makes PhpStorm able to assign `Yii::app()->someComponent` to class for entire project.

Put in CAplication's php doc (above class):

```
/**
 * @property Someclass $someComponent.
 */
```

Solved with one line of code. It works with PhpStorm 9.0, haven't tested earlier versions.